# Save each column of a dataframe in a new dataframe while looping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, while-loop

I have a dataframe called 'Adj_Close' which looks like this:

```
        AAPL      TSLA     GOOG
0       3.478462  NaN      NaN
1       3.185191  NaN      NaN
2       3.231803  NaN      NaN
3       2.952128  NaN      NaN
4       3.091966  NaN      NaN
... ... ... ...
5005    261.779999  333.040009  1295.339966
5006    266.369995  336.339996  1306.689941
5007    264.290009  328.920013  1313.550049
5008    267.839996  331.290009  1312.989990
5009    267.250000  329.940002  1304.959961
```

I want to save each column ('AAPL', 'TSLA' & 'GOOG') in a new dataframe.

The code should look like this:

```
i = 0
n = 3
while i < n:
        df_{i} = Adj_Close.iloc[:,i]
        i += 1
```

Unfortunately it is the wrong syntax. I hope someone can help me...

Comment: I believe columns in a dataframe are their own series. You may look into that more.

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to do that in python would be to create an array of dataframes, as in:

```
dataframes = []
for col in df.columns:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df[col])
    dataframes.append(new_df)
```

The result is an array (`dataframes`) that contains three separate data frames - one for Google, one for Tesla, and one for Apple.

[ One can also define new variables using

```
globals()[my_var_name] = <some_value>
```

But I don't believe that's what you're looking for. 
]